# Replace characters one time loop only problem?

Tags: javascript

I try to replace some codes, but I have 2 problems.

I have codes with : E-1,E-2,E-3,E-4,E-5,E-6,E-7,E-8,E-9 with which I have the problem and all codes is E-1 to E-99

1) E.g. When user writes in text field, system detects only first E-2 and not E-20.

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/\Ε-2/g,"Ε-2 (APPLE)").replace(/\Ε-20/g,"Ε-20 (SAMSUNG)"
```

How do I solve this?

2) I am running this code `onkeyup = function()` but when I write something system replace and replace the words, how I run replace characters only one time?

Comment: _"system detect only first..."_ - I'm surprised that it changes anything at all. Right now this should only throw a syntax error.

Comment: it only detect the first one as **Andreas** said so try to do something like this
`this.value.replace(/\E-(\d+)/, \`E-$1\`)`

Comment: You are missing two closing `)`. Also, your Regex will consider 'E-20' as 'E-2' as well, so you'll get `E-2 ; E-20` turning into `E-2 (APPLE) ; E-2 (APPLE)0`. We'll need a full sample string to know where we can place the boundaries in the RegExp to differentiate between E-2 and E-20.

Comment: @Shilly I hace codes with : E-1,E-2,E-3,E-4,E-5,E-6,E-7,E-8,E-9 who I have the problem and all codes is E-1 to E-99

Comment: Maybe this?: this.value=this.value.replace(/^E-2$/g,"E-2 (APPLE)").replace(/^E-20$/g,"E-20 (SAMSUNG)");

Comment: Where is `E-20` showing up then if your input string is `"E-1,E-2,E-3,E-4,E-5,E-6,E-7,E-8,E-9"`? But we can use the comma as the separator then.

Comment: @Captain_Planet same problem friend, system detect only E-2 first

Comment: @Shilly I need clean codes friend with "out comma"...

Comment: How do you know which `E-` will become which brand? Do you happen to have an object or array like this: `{ "E-2": "APPLE" }` ? Or are you expected to hard code all 99 `E-` combinations?

Comment: @Shilly I try to expected to hard code all 99 E- combinations friend... :-/

Comment: :( Else we could just use a loop. Might still be worth to actually create that object so you can use the replacement function Krzysztof mentions. That would be easier to update later when you have to add E-100 to E-101 when new brands exist. Chaining 99+ different `.replace()` to the same string sounds and looks silly. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Shilly the max number on codes is E-99 so we not need E-100 or 101

Comment: I doubt that there will never be another brand that competes with apple and samsung. ;) I'm just saying we Can if needed, not that we have to right now. It's a good engineering practice to think about future extensions in advance if they don't disrupt the original task.

Answer (score 0):

When we omit the obvious syntax errors of the code you've provided, the problems comes down to replacing multiple values with multiple results in a single replace call. `string.prototype.replace` can take as an argument a function where you can specify the rules of replacing instead of a static value.

Instead of using `onkeyup` you could use `onchange` so that it will only trigger the function after the user is done typing to avoid re-replacing already replaced values.

```js
function updateInput(input) {
  const output = input.value.replace(/E-[0-9]*/g, replaceFunction);
  input.value = output;
}

function replaceFunction(match) {
  // add additional rules here for more cases
  if (match === "E-2") return "Ε-2 (APPLE)";
  if (match === "E-5") return "Ε-5 (SOMETHING ELSE)";
  if (match === "E-20") return "Ε-20 (SAMSUNG)";
  return match;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="updateInput(this)">
```

assuming you had some javascript object in a format where key is the code and value is the replace value, you could simply do

```
function replaceFunction(match) {
  return yourJsonObject[match] || match; // here i return a match in case the rule was not specified inside of yourJsonObject
}
```

Comment: friend @Krzysztof Krzeszewski I use `onkeyup = function (e) {` as input, so the Replacement is done immediately...

Comment: i'd say you probably should just add some flag boolean variable keeping track of whether or not function was executed

Comment: Friend @Krzysztof Krzeszewski work, but we have one more problem, when user try to change again the text and we have Ε-20 (SAMSUNG) as value, then system return Ε-20 (SAMSUNG) (SAMSUNG)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the syntax errors will make the code run.
Adding the comma or end-of-line detecting will differentiate between `E-2` and `E-20`.
If we would not check for the end-of-line, the last `E-` would not get replaced due to missing the comma.

```js
// I have added another E-2 and a couple of E-20 to show that
// 1) All E-2 and E-20 instances gets replaced
// 2) E-2 is not considered part of E-20
const value = "E-1,E-2,E-3,E-4,E-5,E-6,E-7,E-8,E-9,E-2,E-20,E-20";

const replaced = value
  .replace( /(E-2)($|,)/g, '$1 (APPLE)$2' )
  .replace( /(E-20)($|,)/g, '$1 (SAMSUNG)$2' );
  
console.log( replaced );
```

A better solution, since now we know we're dealing with 99 different codes here.
By creating an object we can reference the E- codes from, we can update the E- codes by just adding new ones to the object. The regexp can stay the same.
This should also work on a lot of different strings,since we don't rely on the comma anymore.

```js
// Direct reference to the brand associated with the E- code.
// Since it's a plain object, we could put this in a JSON file we fetch.
// So our sales or marketing department can keep the list up to date.
const brand_reference = {
  "E-1": "",
  "E-2": "APPLE",
  "E-3": "",
  "E-4": "",
  "E-5": "",
  "E-6": "",
  "E-7": "",
  "E-8": "",
  "E-9": "",
  // add E-10 to E-19
  "E-20": "SAMSUNG"
  // add E-21 to E-99
};
// We can use a function as the replacement value.
// The function will use the full match as the first parameter.
// and any capturing groups as the following ones.
// Since we capture "E-someNumber" inside the regex
// p1 will be our full E- code.
// Then we can just use that in a template string to get the correct brand
// And wrap that brand name in ( )
const insert_brand = ( match, p1 ) => `${ p1 } (${ brand_reference[ p1 ] })`;
// .replace() also takes a function as explained above.
const add_brand = str => str.replace( /(E-(\d+))/g, insert_brand );
// Random string containing E- codes. Will come from the input value.
const value = "E-2 E-20 E-2;E-20";
// Updated string that should be set back as the value.
const replaced = add_brand( value );

console.log( replaced );
```

Comment: Added a better solution that is shorter and more extensible than my first solution.